# Persistent Login Cookie With Poltergeist in Rails Not Working

Tags: cookies, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm working on a Rails app, transitioning from using `selenium-webdriver` and `firefox` to using `poltergeist` and `phantomjs` for testing with `capybara` and `rspec`.  It's a large, mature codebase, so predictably I'm running into some troubles.

Where I'm running into issues is when I try to use cookies to login a test user at the beginning of a test.  Poltergeist is set up in my `spec_helper.rb` file like so:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app| 
  options = {
    :js_errors => false,
    :inspector => true,
    :window_size => [1280, 1024]
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

And within `spec/support/helpers.rb` I have the following helper method:

```
def login_as(user,redirect=nil)
  cookie_jar = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.new
  signed_jar = ActionDispatch::Cookies::SignedCookieJar.new cookie_jar,
               AppName::Application.config.secret_token
  signed_jar[:session_31] = {
    value: {
      :'warden.user.user.key' =>
        ["User", [user.id], user.password_salt] } }
  visit '/test.html' unless current_path
  cookie_options = { :expires => Time.now + 15.years }
  page.driver.set_cookie(
        :session_31, 
        cookie_jar[:session_31],
        cookie_options)
  visit redirect if redirect
end
```

Compare this to what I had for `selenium-webdriver`:

```
def login_as(user,redirect=nil)
  cookie_jar = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.new
  signed_jar = ActionDispatch::Cookies::SignedCookieJar.new cookie_jar,
               AppName::Application.config.secret_token
  signed_jar[:session_31] = {
    value: {
      :'warden.user.user.key' =>
        ["User", [user.id], user.password_salt] } }
  visit '/test.html' unless current_path
  page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(
    name: :session_31,
    value: cookie_jar[:session_31])
  visit redirect if redirect
end
```

And then my tests call this helper method in a `before(:each)` block.

```
before(:each) do
  # Setup users and such
  login_as(@user)
end
```

The cookie is created in both cases, but the user isn't logged in with `poltergeist`.  The cookies also appears slightly different when displayed in either case.  With Poltergeist:

```
["session_31",
#<Capybara::Poltergeist::Cookie:0x000fffffffffff
 @attributes=
  {"domain"=>"localhost",
   "expires"=>"Tue, 09 Jan 2029 15:48:08 GMT",
   "expiry"=>1862686088,
   "httponly"=>true,
   "name"=>"session_31",
   "path"=>"/",
   "secure"=>false,
   "value"=>
    "secret ;)"}>]]
```

And with Selenium:

```
[{:name=>"session_31",
:value=>
 "secret ;)",
:path=>"/",
:domain=>"localhost",
:expires=>Wed, 09 Jan 2030 18:40:58 +0000,
:secure=>false}]
```

I don't know if this is a problem with Poltergeist, PhantomJS, my own codebase, or if magical gnomes are causing it.  I'm really at a loss.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why not log in via the UI, as a user would?

Comment: Could you be running into https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/217 ?